# Odd LINQ behavior with Nulls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to handle null properties inside LINQ statements like this:

```
var items = db.Words.Select(w => new WordViewModel
{
    WordId = w.WordId,
    MasterId = w.MasterId,
    MasterWord = ((w.WordMaster == null) ? "is null" : "not null?!?"),
    LanguageName = ((w.Language == null) ? "" : w.Language.LanguageName),
    CategoryName = ((w.Category == null) ? "" : w.Category.CategoryName)
});
```

This seems to work for the LanguageName and CategoryName variables just fine. Unfortunately, the MasterWord variable receives "not null?!?" even when the w.WordMaster property is null.  To make sure the WordMaster property was indeed null, I ran this for loop, which successfully shows the value "IsNull" when I inspect in the debugger.

```
foreach(var word in db.Words)
{
    var str = ((word.WordMaster == null) ? "IsNull" : "NotNull");
}
```

Is there anything dumb I'm missing here?

--Edit--

I think I've found the key difference between the WordMaster and the Category property.  I'm using Entity Framework, so both tie are automatically generated by the respective foreign keys MasterId and CatId.  In the database and the generated model, MasterId is a NOT NULL int, whereas CatId is a nullable.  MasterId still has some entries with a default id that doesn't point to a real Word - these show up nullable in the inspector (looking at db.Words), but apparently not in the LINQ query.  Whereas CatId is actually null, and its Category property correctly shows up as null.

Comment: From the code you've shown I don't think we can deduce anything; basically you're saying that in one situation it works the same as another and we have to take your word for it that the underlying variables have the same values. So if we believe you we have to assume the language is broken. Obviously this is not the case so *something* was different here. Make a small, self contained reproducible sample: if you can reproduce the problem in a manner that we can execute it as well I'll be very surprised. It is very likely a problem in your code you looked over but have not included here.

Comment: I completely agree. Unfortunately, I find LINQ queries very difficult to debug.. Is there any way I can step into LINQ?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can just make a call to `db.Words` and inspect its values in the debugger.

Comment: The data I'm using is also generated semi-automatically by Entity Framework.   One thing to note is that CatId (which lets CategoryName report nulls correctly) is a Nullable<int> in its model's declaration, whereas MasterId (which is tied to WordMaster) is 1 (which doesn't point to anything) instead of actually being null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work-around, and I think can give a better context to the problem.  Since luckily all the incorrect MasterId's have the default value 1, I can simply check to see if (word.MasterId == 1) rather than checking (word.WordMaster==null).  Here's the new code:

```
var items = db.Words.Select(w => new WordViewModel
{
    WordId = w.WordId,
    MasterId = w.MasterId,
    MasterWord = ((w.MasterId == 1) ? "is null" : w.WordMaster.WordName),
    LanguageName = ((w.Language == null) ? "" : w.Language.LanguageName),
    CategoryName = ((w.Category == null) ? "" : w.Category.CategoryName)
});
```

I also made a bogus entry in the Word table that has MasterId == 1, so w.WordMaster.WordName can run without throwing an error.

This works as a temporary solution. I will try to make MasterId nullable and see if that fixes it, but it's a large project so this might take a while.